# Google Drive Api Won't Work In Release App Version

Tags: android, firebase, google-drive-api, google-cloud-console

In My Debug Version Of App , The app works without any error but in release version this happens

```
l9.b: 403 Forbidden
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "insufficientScopes",
      "message": "The granted scopes do not give access to all of the requested spaces.",
      "locationType": "parameter",
      "location": "spaces"
    }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The granted scopes do not give access to all of the requested spaces."
}
```

**Note :** I have registered SHA-1 Keys for signed release apk in the firebase project settings and google cloud console and using google-services.json generated by firebase , I signin in to google and using the google sign in credentials I sign in into firebase.

I don't understand why it won't work since SHA-1 & SHA-256 keys have been registered in cloud console and firebase console for both debug and release version and I am only requesting **appDataFolder** scope which works in debug mode so it should work in release as well !

Comment: Using ``debuggable true`` in release build to capture the error

Comment: It seems the problem is fixed by using that progaurd configuration but I can't test it now since I am getting exception from serialization library , would you like me to delete this question or vote to close

Comment: Thats up to you i already voted this as duplicate